# How do I load the Antetype default widgets to use in my project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, prototyping, wireframe

I'm using the most recent version of Antetype and created a Web Bootstrap project and Wireframe Blank project but cannot see the default Antetype widgets (i.e. radio button, checkbox, dropdown). I searched on Google and Antetype help and support but cannot seem to find how to load in the default widgets. I found that widgets are stored in the Shared library and you pull down the ones you need to your project, but I can't figure out how to view the Shared Library or view **all** of the widgets.

[image: Missing default widgets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.3 of antetype you will find the widgets in each of the templates, you can copy them from the into the shared library. 1.3 shipped with an empty shared library.

In version 1.4 which is due out next month you will find a pre-loaded shared library (renamed to widget library) with 420 new widgets.

Comment: How do I update the L&F of a project to refresh the current Shared Library?

Comment: Also, I copied the radio button from the Windows Tablet template but can't click it when I click Present.